# How can I add superscripts and subscript in a string?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects containing **lots of data or objects** which I import and display in a webpage.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    question: "What is molecular formula for water?",
    options: ["H2O","CO2","H2O","H2O"]
  }
]
```

So Is it possible to write superscript and subscript in a string? To make the numbers superscipted or subscripted while displaying in a webpage.

**Note: I have array of around 1000 objects from which only 100 of them are displayed. Some of them may contain superscript whereas some of them may not. Isn't there any simpler way like using alt codes for super scripts and subscripts so that I can directly put it in string.**

Comment: I think you’re looking for [`<sup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) and [`<sub>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sub)

Comment: You can use CSS to shift elements upwards or downwards and change the size of the characters. You'd have to know what parts of the strings are supposed to be subscripts/superscripts of course.

Comment: `"H<sub>2</sub>O"`

Comment: there are also unicode characters but they are smaller than using html tags https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Comment: @ChrisG when the tags are inside a double inverted comma it is taken as string

Comment: @Slai How can I write unicode characters

Comment: It depends on how the data is displayed, not about the type of quotemark. If you use `.innerHTML`, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` your array of `options` to a formatted version of that option by using `.replace()` to wrap each number in `<sup></sup>` tags to make it appear as subscript text like so:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    question: "What is molecular formula for water?",
    options: ["H2O","CO2","H2O","H2O"]
  }
]

const formatted = arr[0].options.map(elem => elem.replace(/(\d)/g, `<sub>$1</sub>`));

console.log(formatted);
document.body.innerHTML = formatted;
```

Comment: But i have array of around 1000 objects from which only 100 of them are displayed. Some of them may contain superscript whereas some of them may not.

Isnt there any simpler way like using **alt codes** for super scripts and subscripts so that I can directly put it in string.

Comment: What about hydrated salts? Balancing numbers? They don't seem to work in this approach

Answer (score 0):

Regex free approach. Supports hydrated salts (like blue vitorl) and balancing numbers. To add hydrated salts, just add a dot

```js
const arr = [{
    question: "What is molecular formula for water?",
    options: ["H2O", "CO2", "H2O", "H2O"]
  },
  {
    question: "What is the molecular formula for Copper(II) sulphate?",
    options: ["H2O", "(CuSO4).5H2O", "H2O2", "D2O"]
  }
]
arr.forEach(obj => { // map the first array
  let answer = obj["options"].map((options) => { // map all the answers
    let op = options.split('').map((data, i) => { // split all the answer strings
      if (!isNaN(data)) { // if the data is a number the add <sub> tags to it
        if (options.split('')[i - 1] != "." && i != 0) { // if i = 0 is a number then it is a blancing number. Then don't add <sub> tags to it
          // also  check if the previous string is a dot. Means that has water of  crystillization or any other extension
          let str = "<sub>" + data + "</sub>"
          return str
        }else{
          return data
        }
      } else {
        return data // else return the string
      }
    })
    return op.join("") // join the string
  })
  // logic to add data display it
  let question = document.createElement("h1") // question
  question.innerHTML = obj["question"] // append question content
  document.body.appendChild(question) // append the question element to body
  let ul = document.createElement("ul") // create unsorted list
  answer.forEach((things) => { // for each of the answers
    let ali = document.createElement("li") // create a li 
    ali.innerHTML = things // add answers to the lu
    ul.appendChild(ali) // append the li to the ul
  })
  document.body.appendChild(ul) // append the ul to the body
})
```

We are just splitting your answers and checking if the data is a number. If it is then we add `<sub>` tags to it.

To display them, we create elements dynamically and in a loop, we add compounds to a `li` and then append that to a `ul`

Make sure to follow the basic chem rules while formatting compounds

Answer (score -1):

Generic example for replacing digits in all values with [unicode subscript digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) :

```js
var json = JSON.stringify( [ { question: "What is molecular formula for water?", options: ["H2O","CO2","H2O","H2O"] } ] )

var arr = JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => v?.replace?.(/\d/, m => '₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉'[m]) ?? v)

console.log(arr)
document.body.textContent = arr[0].options
```